# How to concat multiple fields to same line with jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

If I run:

```
cat <file> | jq
```

I get:

```
{
  "user": "alex",
  "num": "486",
  "time": "Thu Jun  6 16:26:06 PDT 2019",
  "pwd": "/Users/alex/codes/ores/prompt-command",
  "pid": 11047,
  "exit_code": 0,
  "cmd": "echo '123'"
}
{
  "user": "john",
  "num": "487",
  "time": "Thu Jun  6 16:26:24 PDT 2019",
  "pwd": "/Users/alex/codes/ores/prompt-command",
  "pid": 11108,
  "exit_code": 5,
  "cmd": "echo '456'"
}
{
  "user": "alex",
  "num": "488",
  "time": "Thu Jun  6 16:26:59 PDT 2019",
  "pwd": "/Users/alex/codes/ores/prompt-command",
  "pid": 11141,
  "exit_code": 5,
  "cmd": "echo '789'"
}
```

but instead of all those fields, I just want some output like:

```
alex echo '123'
alex echo '789'
```

so I tried this:

```
cat <file> | jq -r '.user .cmd'
```

but that didn't work I got this error:

> jq: error (at :63): Cannot index string with string "cmd"

I also want to filter it so I only see my commands, something like:

```
cat <file> | jq -r '.user=alex .cmd'
```

Comment: Would just using `grep` here be sufficient? It wouldn't be quite as pretty but you would at least be able to get the two lines you care about

Comment: BTW, it's generally much better form to pass the filename directly to the tool you're running (or to redirect with `<`). Not a huge difference for jq, but for tools like `sort` or `tail` that benefit from seekability, you can get a massive performance difference. (`cat hugefile | tail -n 1` will read `hugefile` beginning to end even though it only needs the last line; `tail -n 1 <hugefile` skips straight to the end. `cat somefile | sort` has to read the file to sort from the first line to the last in order; `sort <somefile` can have parallel subprocesses sorting subsets of the file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good point, thanks

Answer (score 32):

Use `@tsv` to generated tab-separated values as output:

```
jq -r '[.user, .cmd] | @tsv' <yourfile
```

...emits, given your input file:

```
alex    echo '123'
john    echo '456'
alex    echo '789'
```

---

...though if you're filtering for only your user account, you can just print `cmd` directly, since the user value is known:

```
jq -r 'select(.user == "alex") | .cmd'
```

Answer (score 9):

When you write `.user .cmd` you are asking for the "cmd" field of the JSON object at `.user`. To obtain both the .user and .cmd values, you could use the "," operator:

```
.user, .cmd
```

The above, however, will produce two lines.  There are many options for emitting multiple values on a single line.  You might wish to consider using string interpolation; or wrapping the values in square brackets and then using one of `@csv`, `@tsv`, or `join/1`; or using the -j command-line option.

This is all pretty clearly explained in the standard jq documentation (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info), as is the use of `select` for making a selection.